# How to create a single-line script with two for loops, in the debugger, in python 2.7

Tags: python, pdb, django-shell

Creating a single line for loop in the python debugger or django shell is easy:

```
>>>> for x in (1,2,3,4):print(x);
>>>> for x in Obj.objects.all():something(x);
```

But how can I get a second for loop in there?

```
>>>> for x in (1,2,3,4):print x;for y in (5,6):print x,y;
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I care because it's nice to have up arrow edit of the prior command, when working interactively (this is not an attempt to use single line commands in any other context).

NOTE: the "print" is just an example.  In real use I'd iterate objects or perform other programming or debugging tasks such as 'for s in Section.objects.all():for j in s.children():print j'.  I am using Python 2.7.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the times that a list comprehension just won't do

```
for x in (1,2,3,4):print x;exec("for y in (5,6):print x,y;")
```

or

```
for s in Section.objects.all():exec("for j in s.children():print j")
```

Sometimes you can use `itertools.product` (But there's no way to get the `print x`) like this

```
for x, y in itertools.product((1,2,3,4), (5,6)):print x,y)
```

Comment: I would advise strictly against `exec` unless you are hard-coding that part.

Comment: @KaranGoel, the use case is when you're debugging and want to use the up arrow to edit and rerun the line. I think `exec` is ok here

Comment: What I really wanted to do was more like 'for s in Section.objects.all():for j in s.children():print j'

Comment: @Bryce, in that case you need the `exec` version. I added it to my answer

Answer (score 3):

List comprehension may be used to achieve what you want. What you want *exactly* is NOT possible.

```
>>> [(x, y) for x in (1, 2, 3, 4) for y in (5, 6)]
[(1, 5), (1, 6), (2, 5), (2, 6), (3, 5), (3, 6), (4, 5), (4, 6)]
```

Related: [Single Line Nested For Loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17006641/single-line-nested-for-loops)

Comment: But this ignores the `print x` part

Comment: Because list comprehensions build lists with optional conditionals, you cannot print in them.

Comment: `print` is a function in Python3, but once you do that it's getting uglier than using `exec`

Comment: Ah, but this misses the point.  I did not literally want to print numbers.  I was specifically aiming to iterate through objects in each loop.

Answer (score 0):

You could end up putting the command first. For Example.

```
>>> [print("hi") for x in (1, 2, 3, 4) for y in (5, 6)]
```

You do end up with one problem however. Unless you want to call a function at the beginning I do not believe there is a way. For example.

```
>>> [doSomething(x, y) for x in (1, 2, 3, 4) for y in (5, 6)]
```

Comment: >>> [print("hi") for x in (1, 2, 3, 4) for y in (5, 6)]
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Are you using python 3.0 or higher? I just tried this exact same thing using Python 2.7.4 and it did raise a SyntaxError on the `print` function, but then when I tried it in Python 3.3.1 it Worked perfectly fine.

Comment: I'm at the Python 2.7 level, and will likely be for a long time.