# Convert this single-line nested for loop to multi-line in python

Tags: python, for-loop, nested-loops

I am having trouble understanding what the difference is in the code I am modifying here.  The first section is right from [python documentation.](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)

```
def product(*args, **kwds):
    pools = map(tuple, args) * kwds.get('repeat', 1)
    result = [[]]
    for pool in pools:
        result = [x+[y] for x in result for y in pool]
    for prod in result:
        yield tuple(prod)
```

I wanted to make a very similar piece of code but have conditions on when we actually take the product for specific elements in the arguments, so I wanted to convert the line `result = [x+[y] for x in result for y in pool]` into multiple lines, then I could use my if statements and such.  Here is what I did, but when I run it, it seems to get stuck in an infinite loop, or something...

```
def Myproduct(*args, **kwds):
    pools = map(tuple, args) * kwds.get('repeat', 1)
    result = [[]]
    for pool in pools:
        for x in result:
            for y in pool:
                result.append(x+[y])
    for prod in result:
        yield tuple(prod)
```

I would like to actually understand the difference here.  I have read through and think I get [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17006641/single-line-nested-for-loops), but still I am not seeing how to properly convert in this case, or why it is not the same conversion at least.  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you're adding to the list that you're iterating over. So if at first, `result = [[]]` and `pools = [1, 2, 3]`, then after the first iteration over `for x in result`, your list will be `[[], [] + [1]]`, so then you'll grab the second element, etc.

The list comprehension is creating a new list in one line, and then renaming it to map to result.

Be very careful about modifying lists you're iterating over!

Answer (score 3):

Here is an equivalent function:

```
def myproduct(*args, **kwds):
    pools = map(tuple, args) * kwds.get('repeat', 1)
    result = [[]]
    for pool in pools:
        nresult = []
        for x in result:
            for y in pool:
                nresult.append(x+[y])
        result = nresult
    for prod in result:
        yield tuple(prod)
```

Note that `nresult` is created to avoid the problem pointed by [JETM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37349115/5189607).

Comment: Thank you! I wish I could accept both of your answers.  Very helpful.