# Why doesn't my loop work as a single line?

Tags: python, numpy

I have question about using nested single line for loop in python. In particular, I have the followings:

```
A = [[tmp1[a][b] / tmp2[a] for b in range(0,10)] for a in range(0,20)]
```

According to [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17006641/single-line-nested-for-loops), the single line for loop is equivalent as

```
for a in range(0,20):
    for b in range (0, 10):
        A.append(tmp1[a][b] / tmp2[a])
```

However, python gives me the following error:

> AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'append'.

How should I modify the structure so that I use double for loop instead of single line nested for loop?

Update:

```
A=[]
for a in range(0,20):
    B = []
    for b in range (0, 10):
        B.append(tmp1[a][b] / tmp2[a])
   A.append(B)
```

Comment: You did not *initialize* `A` properly... You forgot the `A = []` part.

Comment: It is not a single-line `for` loop; it is a list comprehension. They both simply use the same keyword.

Comment: Append is for native `list`

Comment: You're confusing two very similar lines of of code - the first builds a list of lists, the second a single list: `A = [[tmp1[a][b] / tmp2[a] for b in range(0,10)] for a in range(0,20)]` is not the same as `A = [tmp1[a][b] / tmp2[a] for b in range(0,10) for a in range(0,20)]`

Comment: @Eric, please see my update. Do you agree that the update is equivalent to `A = [[tmp1[a][b] / tmp2[a] for b in range(0,10)] for a in range(0,20)]`

Comment: @wrek :Yes, your update is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you do :

```
for a in range(0,20):
    for b in range (0, 10):
        A.append(tmp1[a][b] / tmp2[a])
```

`A` should be a list to have the attribute `append`:

```
A=[]
for a in range(0,20):
    for b in range (0, 10):
        A.append(tmp1[a][b] / tmp2[a])
```

This method is different it's a [list comprehension](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk) (a way to create the list) :

```
A = [tmp1[a][b] / tmp2[a] for a in range(0,20) for b in range(0,10)]
```

Comment: But I do notice a difference though

Comment: you have different results ?

Comment: Yes, I think you should go:

Comment: `A=[]
for a in range(0,20):
    B = []
    for b in range (0, 10):
        B.append(tmp1[a][b] / tmp2[a])
   A.append(B)`

Comment: where `tmp1` and `tmp2` come from ?

Comment: Please see Eric's comment

Comment: yes sure, sorry didn't read well,  this should work better : `A = [tmp1[a][b] / tmp2[a] for a in range(0,20) for b in range(0,10)]`

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways of setting up your list comprehension

This

```
A = [tmp1[a][b] / tmp2[a] for a in range(0,20) for b in range(0,10)]
```

produces a flat list.

This:

```
B = [[tmp1[a][b] / tmp2[a] for b in range(0,10)] for a in range(0,20)]
```

produces a nested list.

Be sure to note the swap between the two for statements. In the nested case the slowly changing variable comes last, in the flat case it comes first.

The equivalent loops are

```
A=[]
for a in range(0,20):
    for b in range (0, 10):
        A.append(tmp1[a][b] / tmp2[a])
```

and

```
B=[]
for a in range(0,20):
    inner=[]
    for b in range (0, 10):
        inner.append(tmp1[a][b] / tmp2[a])
    B.append(inner)
```