# Nested for loops extending existing list

Tags: python, python-3.x

Explain this code to me. This is a program to print integer inputs as outputs in letters. if i input 35 then output will be thirty five. i understood most of it but want to know how **tens** take the value from

```
twenty thirty forty fifty sixty seventy eighty ninety
```

The code is:

```
num = int(input("Enter the number:"))
numbers = ("zero one two three four five six seven eight nine".split())
numbers.extend("ten eleven twelve thirteen fourteen fifteen sixteen".split())
numbers.extend("seventeen eighteen nineteen".split())
numbers.extend(tens if ones == "zero" else (tens + " " + ones) 
    for tens in "twenty thirty forty fifty sixty seventy eighty ninety".split()
    for ones in numbers[0:10])

print(numbers[num])
```

Comment: Program is working fine no problem. But i want to know how "tens" in the code takes the value from "twenty thirty forty fifty sixty seventy eighty ninety" . Suppose if i input 34 how will tens get "thirty" from "twenty thirty forty fifty sixty seventy eighty ninety"

Comment: @khelwood just c&p'ed the code and it ran as expected without any changes whatsoever. What do you consider wrong with it?

Comment: @shmee You are quite right. I misread it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two main concept that you see in the last line are [list comprehension](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python) and [nested loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17006641/single-line-nested-for-loops). Have a look.

for understanding better what is going on, we're going to split that line in simplier part:

**TENS**

```
for tens in "twenty thirty forty fifty sixty seventy eighty ninety".split():
    print(tens)
```

> OUTPUT: twenty thirty forty fifty sixty seventy eighty ninety

the previous `for` loop correspond to this in list comprehension:

```
(tens for tens in "twenty thirty forty fifty sixty seventy eighty ninety".split())
```

without `print`, returns a generator. if you want to see the result:

```
print(list(tens for tens in "twenty thirty forty fifty sixty seventy eighty ninety".split()))
```

**ONES**

```
numbers = ("zero one two three four five six seven eight nine".split())
for ones in numbers[0:10]:
    print(ones)
```

> OUTPUT: zero one two three four five six seven eight nine

the previous `for` loop correspond to this in list comprehension:

```
    (ones for ones in numbers[0:10])
```

**MERGE FOR LOOPS**

we can merge them:

```
for tens in "twenty thirty forty fifty sixty seventy eighty ninety".split():
    for ones in numbers[0:10]:
        print(tens + " " + ones)
OUTPUT: twenty zero
twenty one
twenty two
twenty three
twenty four
twenty five
twenty six
twenty seven
twenty eight
twenty nine
thirty zero
thirty one
thirty two
[...]
```

since we don't like very much `twenty zero`, we are going to add a clause:

```
for tens in "twenty thirty forty fifty sixty seventy eighty ninety".split():
    for ones in numbers[0:10]:
        if ones == "zero":
            print(tens)
        else:
            print(tens + " " + ones)
OUTPUT:
twenty
twenty one
twenty two
twenty three
twenty four
[...]
```

And this is the same behaviour with list comprehension:

```
(tens if ones == "zero" else (tens + " " + ones) for tens in "twenty thirty forty fifty sixty seventy eighty ninety".split() for ones in numbers[0:10])
```

which returns a list (*[generator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators)) that will be extended to your `numbers` list.
At last, the number that you input correspond to the index of the word in the list

Comment: Thank You Very Much