# is it possible to put two for loop to make list?

Tags: python-3.x

I try to use two for loops in one line with condition 
but it did not recognize the i value

```
 pack = [a,b,c]
    answer =[x== y for x,y in zip(i * int(len(answers)/len(i)) if len(answers)%len(i) ==0  else  i * int(len(answers)/len(i)+1),answers) for i in pack]
```

and it returns the message

> ----> 7     answer =[x== y for x,y in zip(i * int(len(answers)/len(i)) if len(answers)%len(i) ==0  else  i *
>   int(len(answers)/len(i)+1),answers) for i in pack]
>         8 
>         9     answer = [i+1 for i, j in enumerate(answer) if j == max(answer)]
>
> NameError: name 'i' is not defined

Answer (score 0):

'[Single Line Nested For Loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17006641/single-line-nested-for-loops)'

I believe the answer from this linked question will help out overall for the nested loop piece. For the name error with the "i" variable, you are trying to use the variable outside of the scope it is defined.

You essentially have:

```
for x, y in zip
{
//where you are trying to use the variable i before it exists
} 

for i in packs
{
}
```